# Add numbers in hexadecimal base manually

Tags: python, hex

I'm supposed to write a code which gets two numbers in hexadecimal base and calculates their sum without converting bases, which means it should calculate it in hexadecimal base for example:

```
     1 f 5 (A) 
+      5 a (B) 
------------- 
   = 2 4 f
```

and input example for the function would be :

```
>>> add("a5", "17")
```

'bc'

I've written this code so far but I have no clue how to continue, I thought that I would create three loops, one would sum numbers, the other would sum numbers and letters and the third would sum letters.

```
def add_hex(A,B):
    lstA = [int(l) for l in str(A)]
    lstB = [int(l) for l in str(B)]

    if len(A)>len(B):
        A=B
        B=A
    A='0'*(len(B)-len(A))+A
    remainder=False
    result=''
    for i in range(len(B)-1):
        if (A[i]>0 and A[i]<10) and (B[i]>0 and B[i]<10):
           A[i]+B[i]=result
           if A[i]+B[i]>10:
               result+='1'
```

Comment: Your code's indentation is broken, and even with the indentation fixed it will give various syntax errors.  What is your specific question?

Comment: Tips what to do next: Try to run your code and look at the error messages you get.  Most of them should be rather self-explanatory.  If you get stuck with a specific one, you can reduce your code to a minimal example producing this error message, which will usually help you figure out the reason yourself.  If you are stil stuck, you can post the error message and the minimal code here (in a new question) to get help.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the best way to approach the addition/subtraction of hex numbers was using extra functions:

```
def dec_to_hex(number):
    rValue = ""
    hex_bits = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
    while(number):
        rValue = hex_bits[number%16] + rValue
        number = number/16
    return rValue

def hex_to_dec(hex_string):
    hex_dict = {"0" : 0,
                "1" : 1,
                "2" : 2,
                "3" : 3,
                "4" : 4,
                "5" : 5,
                "6" : 6,
                "7" : 7,
                "8" : 8,
                "9" : 9,
                "A" : 10,
                "B" : 11,
                "C" : 12,
                "D" : 13,
                "E" : 14,
                "F" : 15}        
    rValue = 0
    multiplier = 1;
    for i in range(len(hex_string)):
        rValue = hex_dict[hex_string[len(hex_string)-1-i]] * multiplier + rValue
        multiplier = multiplier * 16            
    return rValue
```

and your add function would be

```
return dec_to_hex(hex_to_dec(number1) + hex_to_dec(number2))
```

Comment: I don't to convert the numbers to hex, the input is supposed to be in hex.
I don't really understand what the last loop does, can you please explain?
Thanks

Comment: The loop from dec_to_hex takes the modulo result of number and 16, and so it knows what hex letter to use. Then it divides the number to 16 to get the next letter (it's similar to the algorithm of splitting a decimal number into the <10 numbers it is made of)

Comment: The loop from hex_to_dec takes each letter of the hex string, from the less significant one to the most significant one and adds it to the rValue after looking it up in the dictionary (A=10, F=15 etc) and multiplying it by the corresponding value. It's like turning a binary number into a decimal, only you don't have 2 values, you have 16.

Comment: It looks unnecessary complicated. You could use builtin `int`, `hex` e.g., `add = lambda *args: hex(sum(int(h, 16) for h in args)).replace('0x', '')`